# Evolution 3.10.3 + EWS + Office365 = Calendar hangs client

Tags: gnome, email, evolution, calendar

I upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10. I also updated Evolution from 3.8 to Gnome PPA 3.10. My calendar is no longer accessible in Evolution. When I go to the *Calendar* (i.e. press the *Calendar* button) the screen switches to *Calendar*  and then the Evolution client hangs. It's no longer responsive. I have to kill all the evolution processes, restart the client and quickly click the *Mail* button. Funny thing is though, I still get calendar reminders from Evolution. I just can't seem to manage my calendar in Evolution.

I have tried to delete my EWS account and reconfigure it but to no avail. I have done the **export CAMEL_CASE="all"** command and ran evolution from the command line. When I switch to the *Calendar* no debug information comes forth - the client just hangs.

Is there something else I should try?

Comment: Did you properly update your system? Did you also upgrade evolution-data-server & everything within it which is up-gradable?In any case, first create a backup for `~/local/share/evolution`.Then delete it. Then run evolution. It should recreate the folder. Now try to add EWS & see whether it works or not. Finally report a bug at [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/buglist.cgi?product=Evolution&bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED&version=3.10.x)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have made sure that I am using the a latest available version from their PPA. I have two Office365 accounts. When I reconfigured from scratch, the first account worked fine. When I added the second account that is when evolution locks up. I loaded a laptop with the same configuration and it works fine. The only difference: 32bit vs 64bit. Both running Ubuntu 13.10 + Gnome PPA.